# How do i have a 'Your Ad Here' image in html code? (for a website)

Tags: html

I have searched everywhere for something like a 'your ad here' image, but cannot find the html code for this anywhere.

I have looked all over google.

I am new to html and don't really know anything.

Couldn't find anything, and i expect it to show as an image on my website, where people can pay to advertise in that slot.

Comment: You would just use an image tag with an image you create.

Comment: You should ask yourself: How do I run a webpage if I am not able to add a simple picture to it? That leads you to two possible answers: 1) Right - I ask someone to do it and save myself a lot of troubles 2) I go back to start and learn HTML .. No other way out of this dilemma.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an html tag what you are talking about.

The `<img>` tag will be where you can put a selected image of your choosing (using 
html) and you could use css to make it flash or javascript for that matter.

You could also use an `<iframe>` tag.

Otherwise this is a broad question really because there are a lot of ways you can go about this.

ASP, for example has an Ad Rotator class which displays a different image every time a user refreshes the page. That's C#.

I would advise you check different ad banners from sites that you find appealing and check how they are doing it by hitting F12 in your browser.